# Complex sum with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need help to do a `sum` by using linq in a complex environment

This is the Entities

```
public class Product : EntityBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ReportText1 { get; set; }
        public string ReportText2 { get; set; }
        public bool Standard { get; set; }
        public int ProductGroupId { get; set; }
        public decimal? Surcharge1 { get; set; }
        public decimal? Surcharge2 { get; set; }
        public decimal? Surcharge3 { get; set; }
        public decimal? Surcharge4 { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceIn { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceOut { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceArtisanIn { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceArtisanOut { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceTotalIn { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceTotalOut { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceTotalOutVat { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceAdjustment { get; set; }
        public bool Calculate { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public virtual ProductGroup ProductGroup { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProductArticle> ProductArticles { get; set; }
    }

public class ProductArticle : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductArticleId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceIn { get; set; }
    public bool Primary { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
}

public class Article : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string ErpId { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Specification { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceIn { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ArticleTime> ArticleTimes { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleTime : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int ArticleTimeId { get; set; }   
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }      
    public int TimeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
    public virtual Time Time { get; set; }

}

public class Time : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int TimeId { get; set; }
    public int ArtisanId { get; set; }
    public string Paragraph { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceIn { get; set; }
    public bool System { get; set; }
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
}
```

From Product i want sum Qty in Time.
First from Product, iterate all ProductArticle then inside Article iterate ArticleTime then inside this go to Time and Sum this.

Or is it better create a new column in Product name TotalQty, and in the save method do the sum? The problem is when i add time to Articles the Product entity will not be updated automaticly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly you need a total of Qty

```
var sum = dbContext
          .Products
          .Sum(p => p.ProductArticles
                     .Sum(pa => pa.Article
                                  .ArticleTimes
                                  .Sum(at => at.Qty)));
```